# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Problem 1

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php, project

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
 Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v11.0.0, ..., v11.0.8] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.25.1].
    - league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.15.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.15.0, ..., 3.25.1] require league/flysystem-local ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, ..., 3.25.1].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.15.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, ..., 3.25.1] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^11.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v11.0.0, ..., v11.0.8].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php8\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

I solved this problem by just opening php.ini file and search for ";extension=fileinfo" then remove the ';' and make it this extension=fileinfo and save after. i hope this helps someone also

**;extension=fileinfo**

> extension=fileinfo

Comment: I solved this problem by just opening php.ini file and search for ";extension=fileinfo" then remove the ';' and make it this extension=fileinfo and save after. i hope this helps someone also.

;extension=fileinfo  just un-comment to   extension=fileinfo